# Automatically created files in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

[image][image]

This is my project solution explorer in visual studio 2010,
I highlighted some randomly generated files in various folders. These files were created automatically.

  how these files are generated ?

  if i delete it, will it create any other problems in my web-application ?

  Why these files are generated and how to get rid of it ?

[image]

Comment: We need a closer screenshot of the files.  And have you look in them with a text editor to see what they contain?

Comment: ok,@BlackFrog i put it now.

Comment: (If you can't read the picture right, download, browse to folder and open it to see larger version.) The files seem to have GUIDs as names.

Comment: i hope now you can clearly see the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you if Visual Studio created those files, but I can tell what the file types are.

According to [List of file signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) on Wikipedia and [File Signatures Table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) compiled together by Gary Kessler, the files are in [Zip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_files).

In one of your screenshot the first few bytes of the file are `50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00`. That indicates the file is a [Microsoft Office Open XML Format (OOXML) Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats).

You should rename one of the file to an extension of .ZIP and examine it's content.  That should give you further indication of how the files are created.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have observe the same thing first it is temp files. have you install flash ?

have you tried asp.net caching to make sure that your web app always fetches the latest version of your flash file? I'm not a flash dev, but I would think that if you load the flash every time and don't go to your cache to get it, then the latest xml document would be loaded. Unless flash has an internal caching mechanism.

`<%@ OutputCache Duration="0" VaryByParam="none" %>`  at the top of your aspx page should make sure that everything on that page is fetched every time the page is loaded and nothing is loaded from the cache (temp internet files)

Comment: then also try with <%@ OutputCache Duration="0" VaryByParam="none" %> might be it will work

Comment: @ParthMehta I don't think its a cache issue.  IIS would not store the cache objects in the website folder.